# some pages do not display after deploying

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a perfectly running asp.net c# application, i have windows 7, vs200, vs2010 and sqlserver2008r2 installed on my computer. I use vs2008 for my application. I use web deploy in release mode to generate a package and send it to an administrator to deploy the pack on a testing server. the deployed application works fine for some aspx pages but for some others pages it doesn't find them and displays an error message:

server eror in '/' application
the resource cannot be found
**description:** http 404. the resource you are looking for could have been removed...
**requested url**: /pagename.aspx

thank's for the help
ps: i do not have access or control over the testing server. the application was working fine before my first deploy.

Comment: And is `/pagename.aspx` the correct url? IE should these pages be in the root of the server?

Answer (score 1):

The best explanation is that pagename.aspx isn't at the expected location.

Check if the file is there

If so, check if iis has the right directory for you webapplication

If not, make a correct deployment (do a test deployment on an clean directory).

Comment: all the files are present in the pack. What th eadministrator do is copie past my packed files into the application folder on the server.

Comment: i deployed my pack on my computer and the site is working fine. problem happens only on the server.

Comment: Is the file on the directory on the server? I guess it is not, or you check the wrong directory.

Comment: the file is on the directory on the server. may be some settings need to be changed on my vs2008 when generating the pack but i don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Another hypothesis: It can happen if you are using svn and forgot to add unversion files to subversion.